# Jquery one() function fires twice on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My Jquery `one()` function dies after second click instead of first click. Here is my `HTML`

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="call" data-tai="5">CLICK</div>
</div>
```

and heres my Jquery

```
$('body div').one('click', '.call', function() {
  var mother = $(this).parent();
      if(mother.css('position') === 'static') 
           mother.css('position', 'relative');

  var tai = $(this).data('tai');

  $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/bootstrap/call.php',
      data: 'tai='+tai,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(ret) {
          mother.append(ret);
      },
  });

  return false;
});
```

Interesting thing is, if i don't use `return false;`, it dies after first click. However `bubbling` occurs and it appends 2 html tags instead of 1, inside `box` element. Thanks for help

Comment: _"My Jquery `one()` function dies after second click instead of first click."_ Cannot reproduce. Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('body div')
```

would select both the divs and attach click handlers to both of them. When you click on the nested div then, both clicks will be fired. Use a specific selector to avoid this.

```
$('.call')
```

could perhaps achieve this.

Comment: i have to use `live` events. because there will come many `.call` elements later

Comment: Since my answer points to the problem and offers a solution, can you accept that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

That's because event handlers bound by using `.one` will be fired *once* for *each element* in the jQuery collection. Since the `return false` stops the propagation of the event, if you click on the `.call` element, click handler of the parent element is not executed but the parent element still has an active click handler. You should use a more specific selector for selecting the target element. If the click handler should be bound to the `div.call` elements:

```
$('.box div.call').one(...);
```

Now, if `.box` elements have 9 `div.call` descendants then you have 9 click handlers! After clicking on each element jQuery unbinds the handler for that specific element.

It's not **once for all elements**, it's **once for each element**.

If the handler should be called *once for all the matching elements* you can use the delegation version of the `.one` method:

```
$(document).one('click', '.box div.call', function() {
    // ...
});
```

And if you want to delegate the event and have the handler working once for dynamically generated elements you can use the `.on` method and `:not` selector:

```
$(document).on('click', '.box .call:not(.clicked)', function() {
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  // ...
});
```

Now the handler is called  *once for each `.call` element*. Since `:not` excludes the elements that have `.clicked` class the selector doesn't match the already-clicked elements.

Comment: `body div` and i think there are two divs, so firing for both one.

Comment: an example please. how i can make it more specific?

Comment: `$('.box div.call').one(....)` works, but not for new-comer `.call` elements. On the other hand `$(document).one('click', '.box div.call', function() [})` works for only **1**  time. I mean if i click one `.box div.call`, event dies not for only this element but for all `.box div.call` elements in the page.

Comment: Yes, that's how it's supposed to work, I'll update the answer with another option.

Answer (score 0):

Events bubble in JavaScript.  Your code

```
$('body div').one('click', '.call', function() {
}
```

wires up on both

```
<div class="box"> <!-- This -->
  <div class="call" data-tai="5">CLICK</div> <!-- And this -->
</div>
```

You need a more specific selector.  If this div is a parent element in the body like this:

```
<body>
<div class="box">
  <div class="call" data-tai="5">CLICK</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <div class="call" data-tai="5">CLICK</div>
</div>
</body>
```

then you can use a selector like this:

```
$('body > div').one('click', '.call', function() {
}
```

The question is - where do you expect your click event to be placed?  Perhaps the div with the box class?

```
$('div.box').one('click', '.call', function() {
}
```

This assumes that the .call divs are being added dynamically to the .box div.

P.S. - if you want to stop the bubbling, I suggest you pass in the event object to your click event and call stopPropagation()

```
$('div.box').one('click', '.call', function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation(); // no bubbling
}
```

Comment: I have 2 `.call` divs, just like you showed it. I used `$('body > div').one('click', '.call', funtion() {})` However when i click one of `.call`s the other one does not work. I want both of them work.

Comment: See my fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/xzk55u2g/2/ You can see it calling once per .box. So if you want one click per .box - this is your solution, but if you want one click per .call, then you need a different solution - one where you wire up a one('click') in your success function that appends your .call div.